# Que nome dar para a nossa sala de chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Nossa sala de chat tem o nome apenas de "Portuguese Language". Outras comunidades dão títulos bem mais criativos à sua sala de chat. Por exemplo:

- Stack Overflow em português -> Estouro de Pilha
- Puzzling -> The Sphinx's Lair
- Arqade -> The Bridge
- Open Source -> The Bikeshed
- Physics -> The h Bar
- Information Security -> The DMZ
- Server Fault -> The Comms Room
- Space Exploration -> The Pod Bay
- Sound Design -> The Echo Chamber
- Stack Overflow на русском -> Флудильня имени RU.SO
- Law -> The Sidebar

E em especial, nossos sites irmãos:

- Italian Language -> Bar Sport
- Spanish Language -> La tertulia
- French Language -> Chez Cosette

Se bem que é verdade que muitas comunidade não aderem a essa prática, e o nome da sala de chat é apenas o nome do site.

Então, eis a pergunta:

**Queremos um nome personalizado para a nossa sala de chat? Se sim, qual?**

Comment: Alguém deletou uma resposta que estava mal pontuada, não lembro quem foi.. Acho que essa pessoa poderia deixar a sugestão aqui, ela ao menos serve de mau exemplo :)

Comment: @Math Fui eu, a sugestão era "O dicionário". Rapidamente recebeu vários votos contra e nenhum a favor. Se preferir, eu trago ela de volta a vida.

Comment: Juro que não lembrava que era você, rs.. Mas eu percebi que sumiu um pela contagem das respostas. Bom, pensei que era um bom mau exemplo :) Dá pra mostrar uma boa ideia do que a comunidade **não quer** rs.. Mas é apenas a minha opinião, não sei se realmente é de alguma ajuda.

Comment: @Math Pelo grande número de respostas, sem que nenhuma delas tenha grande aprovação, parece que nunca chegaremos a algo que a maioria goste. :(

Comment: Pois é.. estou achando que levaremos meses para escolher um nome.

Comment: @Math, e se fizesemos igual em eleição? Estas seriam as primárias, e passamos as top votadas pra votação final?  Deixando em destaque na front page por uma semana...

Comment: @brasofilo acho uma semana muito pouco. Gostaria antes de mais nada que o site saísse do beta privado para ver o que acontece. Talvez novos usuários darão novos votos e novas ideias.

Comment: ô, certamente! Tinha que ter dito "tipo uma semana"... e, de novo, na mosca, sair do beta privado é básico :)

Answer (score 6):

## Falatório

> Significado de Falatório
>
> s.m. Vozes simultâneas de muitas pessoas falando; burburinho, murmuração.
> Palavras sem importância; discurseira.
> Conversas, diz-que-diz, mexericos.
> Locutório, parlatório.

Fonte: http://www.dicio.com.br/falatorio/

Comment: "Cacofonia" também é legal :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, merece uma resposta à parte!

Answer (score 6):

## [Tagarelando](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/Tagarelar) (em Português)

Até temos medalha para isso e tudo no SOpt: [Tagarela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/69/outspoken)

> verbo transitivo e intransitivo
>
> 1. [Informal]  Falar muito, geralmente de modo despreocupado ou frívolo. = CAVAQUEAR, LINGUAJAR, LINGUAREJAR, MATRAQUEAR, PALRAR
>
> verbo transitivo
>
> 2. [Informal]  Dizer o que se deve calar; fazer inconfidências.

<sup>[Ou tagarelar](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/143/153)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

## Sarau

> Significado de Sarau
>
> s.m. Conjunto de pessoas que se reúnem para fazer atividades recreativas como: ouvir músicas, recitar poesias, conversar etc; serão. 
>   Show ou concerto musical que ocorre durante à noite.
>   Reunião literária noturna. 
>   (Etm. do latim: seranus/ pelo galego: serão)
>
> Sinônimo de sarau: festa e serão

Fonte: http://www.dicio.com.br/sarau/

Comment: Oxe, então essa é uma tradução possível pra Tertúlia *[{faz nota mental pra não esquecer}]*

Answer (score 4):

> Cacofonia

Que eu já havia sugerido em um comentário

Answer (score 3):

**Fila do Pão**

[image]

Um local onde as pessoas se encontram com humor variado.

Comment: +1 Adoro nonsense :) Só um problema, como é que diz "fila" em Portugal mesmo? rsrsrs

Comment: @brasofilo acho que lá também se diz fila além de bicha rsrs

Comment: @brasofilo Essa pergunta foi na brincadeira, não foi? :P

Comment: @E_net4: yes, my friend, sem xeno nem homofobia :)

Comment: Em Portugal continua a ser [fila](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/114/84), eu nunca entendi a confusão gerada nesse assunto. ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Comment: @brasofilo diz-se mesmo bicha em Portugal até é uma dúvida antiga que tenho: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/551/bichas-ou-filas

Comment: @E_net4: não é minha intenção causar polêmica, escutei essa graçinha sobre fila/bicha de criança, e o Jorge aqui tá dizendo que existe sim, então aqui mesmo temos uma confusão oficial

Answer (score 2):

Tem um duplo sentido não óbvio:

> Conversa fiada

Comment: [O que é o duplo sentido na expressão “conversa fiada”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/513/155) ;)

Comment: @MichalMau: talvez que o pagamento não seja a vista? ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Tertúlia

> Como o espanhol *tertulia*. Significado: [aqui](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tert%C3%BAlia) (assembleia literária) e [aqui](http://www.aulete.com.br/tert%C3%BAlia) (agremiação literária ou encontro de escritores para conversa e leitura).

**Comentário**: embora o que vai acontecer neste nosso chat não seja propriamente um debate entre escritores, se pretendermos que jornalistas ou escritores venham a ser utilizadores deste *site*, parece-me que este nome poderá ser do seu agrado.

Comment: Gosto, invoca não só o informal mas também o lado intelectual desse [tipo de reunião](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tert%C3%BAlia).

Comment: Eu gosto mas prefiro ter um nome único e distinto.

Comment: Gostei deste nome

Comment: Eu descobri essa palavra na Espanha, se por acaso existe no Brasil, deve ser uma *delicatessen* lá da Academia Brasileira de Letras, tipo numa conversa de João Ubaldo com Machado de Assis :)

Comment: @brasofilo aqui usa-se no contexto de conversa entre pessoas intelectuais. Acho que se encaixa no propósito do site, e fica um ironia como "Estouro de pilha" :)

Comment: @JorgeB., palavra perigosa, intelectuais. Em algumas tertulias costuma dar sopapo quando aparece :P

Comment: Tertúlia é uma marca de erva-mate no meu estado :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Tagarelar](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/Tagarelar) (em Português)

Até temos medalha para isso e tudo no SOpt: [Tagarela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/69/outspoken)

> verbo transitivo e intransitivo
>
> 1. [Informal]  Falar muito, geralmente de modo despreocupado ou frívolo. = CAVAQUEAR, LINGUAJAR, LINGUAREJAR, MATRAQUEAR, PALRAR
>
> verbo transitivo
>
> 2. [Informal]  Dizer o que se deve calar; fazer inconfidências.

<sup>[Ou tagarelando](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/150/153)</sup>

Comment: Acho que eu preferiria "Tagarelando", me parece estranho um verbo como nome da sala

Comment: Tagarelando não se usa em Portugal, mas pode ser Tagarelando sim.

Comment: E então "tagarelo"?

Comment: Legal esta, me gusta!

Comment: Acho que deveria colocar uma palavra por resposta, assim não sei qual estão votando a favor ou contra.

Comment: @Orion é tagarelar ou tagarelando.

Comment: Eu sei que é um ou outro, mas qual seria o eleito? Por isso acho que deveria ser respostas diferentes, se não daqui a pouco vão fazer listas de nomes.

Comment: @Orion separei as respostas.

Comment: @Math converteu automaticamente em [comentário](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/105/que-nome-dar-para-a-nossa-sala-de-chat#comment417_105) não sei porquê.

Comment: @Math feito :) [Ou tagarelando](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/150/153)

Answer (score 0):

## Burburinho

http://www.dicio.com.br/burburinho/

Answer (score -2):

> Conversa fora

Da expressão "jogar conversa fora", e uma brincadeira com o fato de o chat set o lugar de conversas *fora* do site.

Answer (score -3):

## Bate-papo

A tradução mais óbvia para a palavra *chat*. :)

Comment: Essa expressão não existe em Portugal.

Answer (score -3):

## Onomasticon

> Júlio Pólux, um estudioso de Alexandria, organizou, por volta de 180 D.C, o seu **Onomasticon**, um dicionário de palavras e expressões agrupadas por assunto

<sup>fonte: [O dicionário analógico](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/07/08/o-dicionario-analogico/)</sup>

Answer (score -4):

Uma sugestão bem simples seria, sendo uma homenagem a terra de origem do Português e traz grande influencia para os demais países.

> Ora Pois!

Comment: Pelos downvotes, acho que isso representa uma visão estereotipada que nós brasileiros temos dos portugueses.

Comment: Eu pensei em uma homenagem, nem de longe quis usar de esteriótipo. Tanto que sou descendente de Portugueses. Já que Portugal é a terra de origem do Português. @bfavaretto

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu votei negativo mas não foi por essa razão, nem sequer me ocorreu tal coisa. Foi apenas por não gostar e haver outra sugestões melhores. Aqui o voto negativo é apenas uma forma de hierarquizar as minhas preferências.

Comment: @ramaral Entendo

Comment: "... e **traz** grande ..."

Answer (score -4):

## Choupana

> Significado de Choupana
>
> s.f. Casa pobre, coberta de palha ou sapê, nos países quentes; cabana, caluje, choça, palhoça.
>
> Sinônimo de choupana: casebre, choça e pardieiro

Pode ser mais pobrezinha:

[image]

Ou mais chique:

[image]

Fonte: http://www.dicio.com.br/choupana/

Comment: Que isso tem a ver?

Comment: É um lugar agradável para ficar com os amigos :)

Comment: Mas o nome não fica "no ouvido"...

Answer (score -5):

### Tasca

> - Estabelecimento modesto que vende bebidas e refeições.
> - Baiuca, taberna.
> - Bodega.

Também pode ser **tasquinha**. É com o intuito de ser um espaço um pouco mais flexível do que a parte principal do site.

Comment: Não funciona no Brasil.

Comment: Pois parece que não. Mas já surgiram outras propostas mais compatíveis.

Answer (score -6):

> **Papo de Boteco**
>
> sig. Boteco - lugar que serve de encontro entre "boêmios", onde se procura uma boa bebida e uma conversa sem compromisso.

Acho que representa bem a informalidade.

Comment: Boteco seria a nossa tasca. Não funciona pelo mesmo motivo que eu disse lá, não atravessa o Atlântico.

Answer (score -7):

> Estado de dicionário

[Homenagem a Drummond](http://drummond.memoriaviva.com.br/alguma-poesia/procura-da-poesia/)